# Find Duplicate Values in a column(s) return with message box the lines

Tags: excel, vba, duplicates, find, msgbox

So I have a forum that users enter in data and I need 2 different checks for duplicate values as they enter them.

right now I have other checks that happen and it Calls modules according to the column the are working on. So these codes would go in separate modules (I have the calls pass the row_value to the modules.

```
x = row_value
```

So my range code looks like something like: `Range("E" & x).Value`

The range I need to look at is from `E7:G307`

The first code I need is to look and see if the `Range("E" & x).Value` they just entered/modified already exists in any other cell in that `E` column. and if so display a message referencing the duplicate line#

So if they enter in "Left Hip" into cell `E10`, it checks all other cells in `E7:E307` to see if "Left Hip" is used in any other `E` cell, and let say `E7 = Left Hip`, then display a message: `"Duplicate found on Line 7"

The second code I need is similar except I need it to look at 2 columns at the same time for duplicates. F & G  and if a match display a message referencing the duplicate line#

So if they enter in "Wasted" into Cell `F10` and "Water" into Cell `G10` then it would look at all other cells in `F7:G307` to see if there is a match on both cells on the same line. So if `F7 = "Wasted"` and `G7 = "Trash"` there is no match, but it `G7 = "Water"` then it would be a match for both columns. and then display a message `"Duplicate found on Line 7"`
Note I would do this check after they entered in the "G" column.

Not sure what other info you need, feel free to ask and thanks for helping.

Note: I have tried to use the `Range.Find` method but cant get anything to work. I just don't understand it enough, I have looked at examples but again not sure how to adapt it to my needs.

Comment: You're already on track to solve your problem, because you are focusing on the requirements of exactly what you want the program to do. Using the `Range.Find` method works fine, as does creating a `Dictionary` and using that for a quick lookup, plus other techniques. Each developer will solve it slightly differently, in their own "best way." We can help you if you post the code you've tried and describe the errors (and which line they occur).

Answer (score 0):

It's always useful passing in a range of values to an array so they can be processed faster. Here's I think a useful start to point you in the right direction. It needs to be modified a bit, like your counter would start at 7 instead of 1.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim value As Variant
    Dim counter As Long

    ''Don't need the empty check, but could be updated to make this static if you wanted to
    Dim values As Variant
    If IsEmpty(values) Then
        values = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A700")
    End If

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1:A700")) Is Nothing Then
        counter = 1
        For Each value In values
            If value = Target.value Then
                If Target.Row <> counter Then
                    MsgBox "Duplicate Value on line: " & counter
                End If
            End If
            counter = counter + 1
        Next value
    End If

End Sub
```